# JMeter starts with warning message

Tags: java, jmeter, startup-error

I have JMeter set-up on my Windows 8 machine.
When I startup JMeter it starts fine but leaves a warning message that I could not understand why.

Here is the log that I see in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Ayusman>jmeter
Dec 20, 2013 12:52:57 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Is any body aware what could be the issue?
I did check the registry information HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft and I do not see a "Prefs" folder in there. But am I supposed to create a registry entry there?

> System Information:

```
Windows 8, 32 bit.
JMeter Version: 2.10
Java Version: 1.7.0_25
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21496098

Comment: Yes indeed, this solved the problem. Thanks. I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @michali mentioned in the comment. Creating a new key `"Prefs"` under `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft"` in Windows registry editor after logging in as administrator did solve the problem.
However JMeter does not create or write anything under this key. Not sure why.

Comment: As mentioned by "san1deep2set3hi", once we run JMeter as an Admin, it will not give this warning next time.. And this is because Jmeter creates registry entry automatically when we run it as a admin..

Comment: The key cannot be created because the bat file doesn't have the rights. When you follow the steps san1deep2set3hi describes the key is created in the admin step.

Comment: I had to manually create the "Prefs" key. Running as Admin with Windows 8.1 and jMeter 5.0 didn't solve it for me as noted in a previous comment. But creating the "Prefs" key fixed it.

Answer (score 30):

To resolve this issue, run jmeter.bat as Administrator once.
After that jmeter can be opened as normal user without this message.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem when I didn't run jmeter.bat as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. Type "where java" in command prompt. Check if, you have more than one java in your environmental variable. If yes, delete the duplicate. You you wont see the error. Otherwise you can run as administrator as mentioned above.